# MixPanelAPI NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, proguard, mixpanel

I'm struggling with **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** when invoking **com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI**

It is because I run *proguard* (I have to). However I added *proguard* exclusion:

```
-keep public class com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.**
```

or

```
-keep public class com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI { *; }
```

but it doesn't help.

Notice worth mentioning is that I get **MixpanelAPI lib** in that way:

```
        compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.0.0@aar"
```

So it's **aar**, not standard **jar**.

How to run it with proguard but not loosing *Mixpanel* code ?

Comment: Running into the same issue, did you find a way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 4.5, Mixpanel advises using the following proguard settings

```
-keep class com.mixpanel.android.abtesting.** { *; }
-keep class com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.** { *; }
-keep class com.mixpanel.android.surveys.** { *; }
-keep class com.mixpanel.android.util.** { *; }
-keep class com.mixpanel.android.java_websocket.** { *; }

-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}
```

You can find these instructions in the README of the Mixpanel library, at https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/blob/master/README.md in the changelog for version 4.5

Comment: Warning:com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks: can't find referenced class com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks$TweakType , this is the warning i am getting on enabling proguard, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This could be the solution:

```
-keep class com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.** { *; }
-keep class com.mixpanel.android.surveys.** { *; }
-keep class com.mixpanel.android.util.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in incorrect MultiDex implementation, I solve it after add to main class MultiDex.install(this);

```
public class MyMainClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        MultiDex.install(this);
...
}
```