# Proguard and mixpanel issue

Tags: android, proguard, mixpanel

On enabling proguard, I am getting the following warning

**Warning:com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks: can't find referenced class com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks$TweakType
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
:app:proguardStageRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardStageRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.**

logcat on putting -dontwarn com.mixpanel.**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.leadsquared.app.LeadsActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2546)
        at android.support.v4.app.o.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.k.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.app.aj.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.k.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.internal.a.b.g(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.internal.a.c.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

proguard-rules.pro file is like this

```
  -dontshrink
 -dontoptimize
 -dontpreverify
   -dontwarn okio.**
      -dontwarn com.mixpanel.**
  -keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
    -dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
    -dontwarn com.squareup.**
      -keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
     -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
       void onClick*(...);
      }
      -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
      *** *Callback(...);
         }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Maybe have a look at this and try the proguard settings listed in the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663713/mixpanelapi-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: in my case exception is different , so it does not work

Comment: It maybe an issue with shrinking. Try this option in proguard configuration: "-dontshrink".

Comment: I have tried this but there is error which comes when token is not provided to fetch data

Comment: @MarcelTricolici on using this I am getting this    No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/mypackage

Comment: Add your proguard confirugation please

Comment: @MarcelTricolici I have posted

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your proguard config:

```
-dontwarn com.mixpanel.**
```

see also [here](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-to-compile-android-with-proguard)

Comment: On putting this my app crashes

Comment: Would you post the logcat-output?

Comment: I have posted the logcat output

Comment: Would you please try what happens if you set `-keep com.mixpanel.**`?

Comment: Yes i have tried it , on putting this, there is error while loading data

Comment: I mean I am not able to fetch data using okhttp from the server, I am not sure this problem is due to okhttp